# Rails mountable engine use db schema from main application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I'm creating a rails engine for an application i'm working on.

Basically the application is split into two sections:

1. Private
2. Public

The private site is the main application where all the admin functionality lives and the public site (engine) should be able to access the models from the private app.

It sounds like its in reverse to me but this is what the spec calls for.

I know in general you would access an engine model in your main app as such:

EngineName::Model

How would I access the main application inside the engine?

Example:

A private user would go to foo.bar/videos/new and create a new video.

A public user would go to foo.bar/public/videos and have access to those same videos.

Comment: Splitting the functionality into private and public sections makes sense, but why does this situation require you to use the Engine pattern?

Comment: I guess it's a good question, but it seems like you're jumping through unnecessary hurdles. What are you really trying to accomplish by doing it this way, besides satisfying the "spec"? Was the spec written by a programmer?

Comment: Normally I would package functionality into an Engine because I want to reuse it elsewhere. If the engine contains calls to code from the host application, then it won't be reusable. In that case, I'm curious about what benefit you're trying to get from writing it as an engine. If you just want to draw a clear line between what's public and what's private, it might be [easier to use a namespace](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this out and was able to reference code from the host application inside an engine without any trouble.

```
# In the main application
# lib/test_library.rb
TestLibrary
  def self.say_something
    "Hello! I am defined in the host application, not the Engine."
  end
end

# Then, inside the engine
# app/views/your_engine_name/some_resource/index.html.erb
<%= TestLibrary.say_something %>
```

This prints just fine in the Engine template. So if you have a `Video` model you can refer to it in the controller inside your engine, just like you would if the controller were part of your application.

With that said, I'm not sure the Engine pattern is the best fit for your requirements.

Writing it this way means you can't reuse the Engine code elsewhere, and if reuse isn't what you care about then an Engine is probably a more heavyweight solution than you need. You might consider using a [namespace](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

Comment: Thank you and yes I totally agree that a namespace makes way more sense but my team lead wants it done this way and I appreciate your solution!